# Android Kotlin - Can't understand how to pass values in an sdk library ( containing an activity)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, module

I am having a headache understading how to pass values to an activity inside a library.
I have created a library that contains an activity ( Lets call that activity ShowEmailActivity).
Inside ShowEmailActivity I have got a variable called email of type string and a function called setEmail that takes as a parameter a string.
(example: fun setEmail(email:String){this.email=email})
What i want to do is to show this email as a textview inside my xml ( this is not hard, I know how to do this ) 
When I add my library as a module depedency from File ->Project structure -> Dependencies ( I then select my main application ) -> + Module depedency Everything works well. 
I can even call the ShowEmailActivity from my MainActivity inside my application. 
However, what i want to do is to call setEmail function from ShowEmailActivity so that i can set my email from the MainActivity. 
What i thought of doing was to create an object of that class inside my MainActivity Class:

```
val showEmailActivity = ShowEmailActivity() 
showEmailActivity.setEmail(myEmail)
```

However , when i open an intent  to open my ShowEmailActivity , nothing happens. 
I am clearly doing something wrong, can anybody suggest anything ?
Thank you.

Comment: Look at this answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/2091482/16552338. You can send your mail by intent.

Comment: I don't want to send it by intent because I also want to send other data ( like mutable list ) . The email function that I mentioned is just an example.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to instantiate an `Activity` and that will not work because this is done by the Android system itself

So if you need to call a specific method say `sendEmail` in your case as soon as the Activity is created or in Java terms an instance is made and having a parameter as `myEmail`, you can use the `onCreate` method of your activity

Let me add some sample code to help you with your case

Say we have your activity `ShowEmailActivity` , first we will make an intent to start the activity, and we will also pass `myEmail` as a `Bundle` argument

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, ShowEmailActivity.class);
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("email_extra",myEmail); // Here you can add as many bundle arguments as you want
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

Now inside your library or where your `ShowEmailActivity` is defined, we will call the `setEmail` method inside the `onCreate` method because [`onCreate`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onCreate(android.os.Bundle)) is called as soon as the activity is created by the Android System

```
class ShowEmailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  @Override
  void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     if(getIntent.getExtras().getString("email_extra") == null){
        thrown new IllegalStateException("email_extra inside bundle cannot be null"); // Case when someone forgot to pass this bundle extra, this will be thrown
      }
    String myEmail = getIntent().getExtras.getString("email_extra")
    setEmail(myEmail)

  }

  private void setEmail(String email){
     // Your function implementation here
  }

}
```

Please correct syntatical errors if any, because I'm used to IDE corrections

Comment: Thanks for your response. I already knew how to do that with .setExtra but I was wondering if I could access the setEmail and set the email before I create the intent. 
As it turns out by what you are saying I can't. 
Thank you very much for your time explaining it!

Comment: Why would you exactly want to do it before the intent when the entire logic of that method lies inside the `Activity`? I mean, I just want to understand your user case with it

Comment: Maybe I am just confused. Let's say for example , we have a recyclerview , when you impement a recyclerview you first call the layoutmanager and then you call the adapter method. I am thinking that all those methods in order to create the recyclerview are prerequirements. If you dont give a layoutmanaer or a adapter then the recyclerview cannot be created. 
Thats what i have in mind. To create an activity that  has prerequirements before you create it.

Comment: Then you are on the right track my friend, the `onCreate` method is exactly where your `pre-requirements` will go because before that , the `Activity` is just another java object in the memory.Do your pre requirement thing, and then call `setContentView` to set the UI for your user